# Making rounded triangle shape using CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have been trying to create this shape in the bottom left and top right corners of the page. Unfortunately, I have not been able to create the desired look the closest that I have been able to achieve is a pie shape with the following code:

```
<style>

  /* css code that will create, color, and shape
     the first accent color area */
  #colorAreaOne{

    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    background: #3333ff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 0 700px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 700px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 700px 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;

  }

  /* css code that will create, color, and shape
     the second accent color area */
  #colorAreaTwo{

    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    background: #3333ff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 0 0 700px; 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 700px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 700px 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;

  }

</style>
```

If anyone has any information it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is missing HTML, please add it.

Answer (score 6):

A radial-gradient

```css
div {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent 0%, transparent 700px, black 700px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use a square and use a round pseudo to fill parts of it with a shadow

```css
div {
  height:50vw;
  width:50vw;
  bottom:0;      
  position:fixed;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
div:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:0  0 0 50% ;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50vw turquoise;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden;`

```css
.shape{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.shape:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 400px solid;
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick solution that will work if pseudo element is same color as background.

```css
.el {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px;
}
.el:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```